# WPF Window occupies maximum screen available space

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Consider a WPF Window with no Width/Height specified and `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"`, where the content is dynamically set, say in code behind somewhere:

```
win.Content = new UserControlWithDataGrid();
```

Where UserControlWithDataGrid is something like this:

```
<DataGrid Height="600">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Name" Width="*" Header="Name"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The produced window will grow to the available screen space, because the only element 'constraining' `Width` is the DataGridTextColumn. But since its `Width` is set to 'occupy the entire available space', it grows until it finds a limit.

That being said, I don't want to specify a `MaxWidth` on the Window, because I simply don't want to constraint it. I don't want to specify a `Width` on the Window, because I want it to adjust to it's content, as in this case there's `UserControlWithDataGrid` but I may dynamically change it to `UserControlWithSomethingElse`.

So, is there a way to open the window with the minimum necessary with instead of the maximum allowed, preferably without having to derive from `Panel`?
Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is the "minimum necessary width"? Can't you just set the column's MaxWidth?

Comment: I want the Column to stretch to the DataGrid width, so no.

Comment: And that is as wide as possible, i.e. as wide as the screen. You won't get around setting some limit somewhere. The layout system can not guess any "minimum necessary width".

Comment: Hence my question. There's got a be some workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use SizeToContent property to achieve your desired result.
More info on the property:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.sizetocontent?view=net-5.0

Also, optionally, you can restrict user from resizing the window to lower values than the content needs:

```
public MainWindow() {
  InitializeComponent();
  this.SizeToContent = System.Windows.SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
  this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
}

void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  this.MinWidth = this.Width;
  this.MinHeight = this.Height;
}
```

upd: currently your content width is set to "*". So it's not limited anyhow and will take the whole space. You will need to limit it somehow, in case you want your window to open not in full width

Comment: Thank you, but I think you missed the first line where I say that SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight". If you try your code, you'll see that the window will occupy the entire screen Width, therefore keeping the issue I've stated.

Comment: And have you checked WindowState value?

Comment: Please check out the update answer. If you don't have WindowState set to Maximized, should help

Comment: The window isn't maximized at opening, it simply (and logically) opens occupying the entire available width. The goal is to keep the window resizable, adaptable to its content but don't use the maximum available width when no upper limit is found among the controls.

Comment: Yeah, so the thing is, that Width="*" set's the lower limit